# "Type Error" issue when fetching API in Firefox and Edge with CORS

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cors, fetch, http-redirect

I'm writing a API call with Fetch() to download a file from another Domain. The process is: A fetch() method is calling in DomainA to an API in DomainB, then the API returns the response with location in repsonse's header, the location is an url of DomainC.

In Chrome and IE, it works well. Based on the Network Inspection, we can see 3 http requests here.

- A. An OPTIONS request to the API, the response Status code 200;
- B. An GET request to the API, and the response status code is 302 and
  in the response Header, location property contains the target file
  location (http url).
- C. A request to the target file location to download the file.

But in Firefox and Edge, we can only see the request A) and B). Both of their responses are expected. While there is no 3rd request to download the data. Within debugging, we can see an error is thrown in the fetch().catch(error){}, the error is TypeError:
In Firefox:

- *TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.* In Edge:
- *TypeError: Failed to fetch*

I just did some investigation on this issue.
According to [Http-redirect fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-http-redirect-fetch), it should work well since CORS is configured correctly. I guess Firefox or Edge may implement their native fetch() method which leads an failure here.

Does anyone know what's going on here? Thanks.

Comment: I have exact the same problem with firefox :(

Comment: I opened a bug report @mozilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1469349